# How to animate scroll position of div with overflow: auto?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a function which scrolls given div or body to an element's location within. Currently it looks like:

```
function scrollTo($elem, offset, delay, $context){
    delay = delay || 800;
    offset = offset || 0;
    $context = $context || $('html, body');
    $context.animate({
        scrollTop: $elem.offset().top-offset
    }, delay);
}
```

It works fine on body, however, when I give it $context the first call works as intended, but all the consecutive calls are scrolling to a wrong position.

Why is this behavior and how to fix it?
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/a8jc5q6r/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `offset().top` measures the distance from the top of the page to the element.

- When you click `.1`, the offset distance to the top of the page is `300`.
- Once `.large` which is now `-300` is scrolled to that position, `.1` offset becomes `0`, `.2` becomes 300, `.3` becomes `600`.
- so you need to minus the offset of `.large` to get the real position.

Code

```
function scrollTo($elem, offset, delay, $context){
    delay = delay || 800;
    offset = offset || 0;
    $context = $context || $('html, body');
    var a = $context.find('.large'); //need this
    $context.animate({
        scrollTop: $elem.offset().top - a.offset().top
    }, delay);
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/a8jc5q6r/4/